# How can I duplicate an array of pointers in C? (uint32_t)

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, memory, centos

I have the following variable "places" which is a ptr to a dynamic array of string locations:

uint32_t* places;

I would like for my function to return a DUPLICATE pointer of type (uint32_t*)

My current attempt:

```
uint32_t arrCpy = malloc((numberOfElements) * sizeof(uint32_t));
memcpy(arrCpy, places, sizeof(uint32_t*)*numberOfElements);
return arrCpy;
```

Please explain what I am doing wrong and how to resolve this issue? I am receiving a segmentation fault using gcc.

**Correction:
Goal is to take a uint32_t* and make a duplicate uint32_t*
"Note that the function returns a duplicate
of the array of locations for the key, not a pointer to the original array stored in the hash table. The rationale for this is that
returning a pointer to the original array would be dangerous because it would allow the user to directly modify the original
array."

Comment: `places` here is just a pointer (or a pointer to an array). If it's an *array of pointers*, it's type should be `uint32_t **`

Comment: You are correct Mustafa, I mistyped my question. Just corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uint32_t* places;
```

> I would like for my function to return a DUPLICATE (not the same)
> pointer which points to the same array of strings.

If you wrote exactly what you need, it is just a pointer pointing to the same array. But it is not an array of strings, it is an array of pointers to 32-bits `int`

- if you need to pass a pointer to the existing array of pointers, it is just the case of writing

```
    uint32_t*     to_the_same_places = places;
```

`places` has the address of the start of the array of pointers, so you just need to copy `places`.

- if you need to duplicate the array of pointers, but pointing to the same places, you are in the a situation similar at the start of every program: you need to know how many pointers are in `places`. This is why `main()` is declared

```
int    main(int argc, char** argv);
```

`argc` comes just in time with the number of pointers, so the system can build the array and you can iterate over them.

#### if you know the size and need to duplicated everything

This is the common scenario, as the source of `places` addresses can go out of scope and invalidate the full block that `places` points to. Since the new array will point to the same locations you need to go in 2 steps:

- you need to allocate an area to hold all the pointers. The size is the number of pointers times the size of a pointer in your machine. The pointers are aligned in memory so you can copy the whole block at once using `memcpy()`
- you need to create a pointer that points to the new array. No need to use `uint32_t**`

You can reverse the steps.

But you need to know how many pointers `places` points to, and may be more practical just go the system way and write a pair like `int argc, char** argv`

Answer (score 1):

`uint32_t* places;` is not an array of pointers, it's a pointer to `uint32_t`, a number. Generally, to have an array of `something`, you should have an pointer pointing to `something`. So you may want to declare your `places` like `uint32_t** places;`, and so is arrCpy.

```
uint32_t** dup(uint32_t** places, int numberOfElements)
{
    uint32_t **arrCpy = malloc((numberOfElements) * sizeof(uint32_t*));
    memcpy(arrCpy, places, sizeof(uint32_t*)*numberOfElements);
    return arrCpy;
}
```

---edited---

If you want to duplicate an array of `uint32_t`:

```
uint32_t* dup(uint32_t* places, int numberOfElements)
{
    uint32_t *arrCpy = malloc((numberOfElements) * sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(arrCpy, places, sizeof(uint32_t)*numberOfElements);
    return arrCpy;
}
```

You can see no matter what array you want to duplicate, you create an pointer, allocate its memory then copy it, and then return that pointer.

---edited---

an complete code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int* dup(int* places, int n)
{
    int *arrCpy = malloc((n) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(arrCpy, places, sizeof(int)*n);
    return arrCpy;
}

void main()
{
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%u, ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // print 1,2,3

    int *b = dup(a, 3);
    a[0]=100;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%u, ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    // print 100,2,3
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("%u, ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //print 1,2,3
}
```

Comment: I mistyped my question, I need the return value to be a uint32_t*

Comment: Goal is to take a uint32_t* and make a duplicate uint32_t*

Comment: then "an array of pointers" is not what you want, an array of `uint32_t` is?

Comment: I just want to take the uint32_t* and make a duplicate of it

Comment: "Note that the function returns a duplicate
of the array of locations for the key, not a pointer to the original array stored in the hash table. The rationale for this is that
returning a pointer to the original array would be dangerous because it would allow the user to directly modify the original
array."

Comment: I am still confused. In my code, I am able to say something along the lines of places[index] = newValue and it works fine... after duplicating, I cannot take arrCyp[index] = newValue... I get a syntax error.

Comment: @kylepapili I add an complete code. I'm guessing here you got a Segmentation Fault because of incorrect memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

`arrCpy` needs to be a (double) pointer. If it's an array of pointers, you also need to allocate space for `num` *pointers*, not values.

```c
// `places` should have type uint32_t **
uint32_t **arrCpy = malloc((numberOfElements) * sizeof(uint32_t*));
memcpy(arrCpy, places, sizeof(uint32_t*)*numberOfElements);
return arrCpy;
```